# Creation for the tag synonym 'Red Dog'?

Tags: support, tags

I have tried to see if there is actually a tag for the movie Red dog.

I wanted to ask a question about Red Dog but I don't have the reputation to create tag synonyms.

I checked the tag synonyms on the main site but it isn't there.

**Can we create it if possible**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag's can be created by anyone with 300 reputation or more, you don't need to ask for a tag to be created.  You can create a new tag by typing it into the tags field on the question form.

You can view the list of your privileges here:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Tag synonyms are not the same as tags, which is a feature to help fix incorrect tags.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: Note that if natural uses the mobile app to view Stack Exchange, you can not create new tags from the app.